# Displaying orbital node characters in groff ms macros

Tags: unicode, postscript, groff

I'm trying to display the characters for ascending and descending orbital nodes (☊ and ☋) in groff, however when I export the document to postscript they simply don't show.

Answer (score 3):

There is quite a bit of work to get unusual characters into a PostScript document with groff. First you need to choose a font that contains the character. Googling for the name and the tag *unicode* can find for example this [site](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/260A-ascending-node) which says that, for example, it is found in font DejaVuSans-Bold, which I happen to have on my system in ttf format.

You need to convert the ttf to the format wanted by groff.  I created a directory `/tmp/font/devps` and in it ran

```
ttf2pt1 -a -e /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf DejaVuSans-Bold
```

where `ttf2pt1` came from a package of the same name on my system. This created the files `DejaVuSans-Bold.afm` and `DejaVuSans-Bold.pfa`. They need more conversion with

```
afmtodit DejaVuSans-Bold.afm textmap DejaVuSans-Bold
```

where `afmtodit` came from package `groff-perl`.  This created file `DejaVuSans-Bold` which can now be referenced from groff by the command

```
.ft DejaVuSans-Bold
```

provided you have told it where to find it by doing

```
export GROFF_FONT_PATH=/tmp/font
```

before running `groff -Tps`. You also need to refer to the character by its unicode value in the input text, eg:

```
here \[u260A] there
```

(If your input file is in utf-8 you may be able to have this conversion done for you by adding groff option `-K utf-8`, which I have not tried).
Here's a set of commands that worked for me (you may need to change the origin of the ttf file):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/font/devps
cd  /tmp/font/devps
ttf2pt1 -a -e /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf DejaVuSans-Bold
afmtodit DejaVuSans-Bold.afm textmap DejaVuSans-Bold
export GROFF_FONT_PATH=/tmp/font
groff -Tps >text.ps <<\!
.ps 20
.vs 24
.ft DejaVuSans-Bold
here \[u260A] there
!
gv text.ps
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, they still wont display.