# Can't use different font families in groff -ms

Tags: fonts, unicode, postscript, groff

I'm using `groff` with `ms` macros and outputting it to PostScript. On Linux Void. I want to have a different font and also output Unicode characters. I have converted my font as written in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533032/displaying-orbital-node-characters-in-groff-ms-macros) question. As specified, it worked for me (with NO `ms` macros). Yet it doesn't display a title, an author and headings properly (not at the center, no special formatting).

```
.ft linlibertine_rah
.TL
Title
.AU
Author
.NH
Heading
.PP
\[u1E6C]
```

outputs to:

[image]

If I compile the same docuemnt with the `-ms` option, I get a document with 'Times' font and no Unicode symbols (but properly formatted):

[image]

It is specified in `groff_ms` manual that font family is specified with the `.FAM` string, but result is the same as with `.ft`. It also outputs to console:

```
troff: test.ms:9: warning: can't find special character 'u0054_0323'
```

It definitely has detected the font, as with `.ft samplefont` it outputs:

```
troff: test.ms:1: warning: can't find font 'samplefont'
troff: test.ms:9: warning: can't find special character 'u0054_0323'
```

So my question is: how do I use a different font family in `groff` with `ms` macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `FAM` string to specify a font family you will need to use conventional names with the suffixes `R B I BI` for roman, bold, italic, and bold-italic. In the linked-to [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533032/displaying-orbital-node-characters-in-groff-ms-macros), the font family was `DejaVuSans`, so you need to provide fonts `DejaVuSansR`, `DejaVuSansB`, `DejaVuSansI`, and `DejaVuSansBI`. The following worked for me:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/font/devps
cd  /tmp/font/devps
convert(){ 
  from=${1?} to=${2?}
  ttf2pt1 -a -e "$1" "$2"
  afmtodit "$2".afm textmap "$2"
}
convert /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf DejaVuSansR
convert /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf DejaVuSansB
convert /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf DejaVuSansI
convert /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf DejaVuSansBI
export GROFF_FONT_PATH=/tmp/font
groff -Tps -ms >text.ps <<\!
.ps 20
.vs 24
.ds FAM DejaVuSans
.TL
Title
.AU
Author
.NH
Heading
.PP
roman \[u1E6C]
.B "bold \[u1E6C]
.I "italic \[u1E6C]
.BI "bolditalic \[u1E6C]
!
gv text.ps
```

[image]